# How to make a call via SIP protocol to landline phone in ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, call, sip

I m working on a iPhone application to make a call from SIP protocol to landline phones, i got some samples to make a call from SIP to SIP but i did not get any solutions to make landline call from SIP protocol, please help me to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From Apple Documentation ...

A Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP) app allows the user to make phone calls using an Internet connection instead of the device’s cellular service. Such an app needs to maintain a persistent network connection to its associated service so that it can receive incoming calls and other relevant data. Rather than keep VoIP apps awake all the time, the system allows them to be suspended and provides facilities for monitoring their sockets for them. When incoming traffic is detected, the system wakes up the VoIP app and returns control of its sockets to it.

There are several requirements for implementing a VoIP app:

Add the UIBackgroundModes key to your app’s Info.plist file. Set the value of this key to an array that includes the voip string.

Configure one of the app’s sockets for VoIP usage.

Before moving to the background, call the setKeepAliveTimeout:handler: method to install a handler to be executed periodically. Your app can use this handler to maintain its service connection.

Configure your audio session to handle transitions to and from active use.

To ensure a better user experience on iPhone, use the Core Telephony framework to adjust your behavior in relation to cell-based phone calls; see Core Telephony Framework Reference.

To ensure good performance for your VoIP app, use the System Configuration framework to detect network changes and allow your app to sleep as much as possible.

Including the voip value in the UIBackgroundModes key lets the system know that it should allow the app to run in the background as needed to manage its network sockets. This key also permits your app to play background audio (although including the audio value for the UIBackgroundModes key is still encouraged). An app with this key is also relaunched in the background immediately after system boot to ensure that the VoIP services are always available. For more information about the UIBackgroundModes key, see Information Property List Key Reference.

Try this link .. this might help 
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451076/implementing-the-sip-functionality-in-ios5)